# Unable to get a channel in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I have been making a suggestions command in `discord.js` and I keep getting the following error:

`Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined`

Here is my code, I have tried changing it in many ways but it doesn't work.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "suggestion",
    aliases: ['suggest', 'suggestion'],
    permissions: [],
    description: "suggetion command",
    execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
        let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("865868649839460353");
        if (!channel)
            return message.reply('A suggestions channel does not exist! Please create one or contact a server administrator.')
            .then(message => {
                message.delete(6000)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Was the message written in a private channel?

Comment: How do you call the `execute()` method?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(message)`?

Answer (score 1):

1st idea: The channel you're executing in is not a guild.

By fixing this, you can do:

```js
if(!message.guild){
     return
}
```

2nd idea: You may have specify the wrong channel in the wrong server. Do the following:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(`YourGuildId`)
let channel = guild.channels.cache.get(`ChannelId`)
```

or

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(`${message.guild.id}`)
let channel = guild.channels.cache.get(`ChannelId`)
```

I hope these idea helped you! <3

Comment: I actually copied the wrong id, i had not copied the channel id, ty for the reply :D